# What's the regular expression to find the last digit in a string?

Tags: c#, regex

My brain must be frazzled but I can't get this to work and I've very little experience with regular expressions.

I have a string such as "gfdsgfd354gfdgfd55gfdgfdgfs9gfdgsf".

I need a regular expression to find the last digit in the string - in this case the "9".

### EDIT

I should have been clearer but, as I say, I'm frazzled.

It's to insert a hyphen character before the final digit. I'm using C# Regex.Replace. Using the idea already suggested by Dave Sexton I tried the following without success:

```
    private string InsertFinalDigitHyphen(string data)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(data, @"(\d)[^\d]*$", " $1");
    }
```

With this I can process "ABCDE1FGH" with the intention of getting "ABCDE-1FGH" but I actually get "ABCDE-1".

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: OP, I edited my answer for your C# replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this one :

```
(\d)[^\d]*$
```

**EDIT :**

You initially mentioned only a match, no language and no replacement. For your C# replacement, you should use

```
private string InsertFinalDigitHyphen(string data) {
    return Regex.Replace(data, @"(\d)(\D*)$", " $1$2");
}
```

Comment: Ah, I missed the $2. Said I was frazzled! Thanks for the Help.

Answer (score 5):

I always find regular expressions hard to read, so you could do it in an alternative way with the following LINQ statement:

```
string str = "gfdsgfd354gfdgfd55gfdgfdgfs9gfdgsf";
var lastDigit = str.Last(char.IsDigit);
```

Output:

```
9
```

To insert a hyphen before this one, you can use `LastIndexOf` instead of `Last` and use that index to insert the hyphen at the correct location in the string.

Comment: Good point. +1 for the answer but I still want to know the regex :)

Comment: If you need the index: str.LastIndexOf(str.Last(char.IsDigit));

Answer (score 2):

If it is the last single digit you want the use this:

```
(\d)[^\d]*$
```

If it is the last set of digits then use this:

```
(\d+)[^\d]*$
```

EDIT:

You need to pick out the capture group (the bit in the brackets) - for c# I think it would be something like this:

```
Regex.Matches("gfdsgfd354gfdgfd55gfdgfdgfs9gfdgsf", '(\d)[^\d]+$')[0].Groups[1].Captures[0].Value
```

Or alternatively to avoid capture groups you could use a look behind regex like so:

```
\d(?=[^\d]+$)
```

Comment: Tried that but when I do the replace it replaces everything from the last digit to the end of the string, rather than just replacing the last digit. So ABCDE1FGH should become ABCDE-1FGH but actually becomes ABCDE-1. I guess it's matching 1FGH instead of just 1.

Comment: Add to my answer now that I know you are using c#.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with [String.LastIndexOfAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d15dfa1.aspx):

```
private string InsertFinalDigitHyphen(string data)
{
    int lastDigit = data.LastIndexOfAny(new char[] {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']);
    return (lastDigit == -1) ? data : data.Insert(lastDigit, "-");
}
```